# Why doesn't my Word macro for saving as PDF show up in Recent Items?

Tags: vba, ms-word, export-to-pdf, recent-file-list

MS Word Macro Save as Pdf not showing up in Recent Items

If I use the File Save as PDF the filename.pdf shows in the Recent Items.

If I use this macro to create the PDF the Filename.pdf doesn't show in the Recent Items list.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
'
' Silent SaveAsPDF Macro
'
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Application.RecentFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.recentfiles) property for adding your files to the history of recent files.

Use the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.recentfiles.add) method to add a file to the `RecentFiles` collection. The following example adds the active document to the list of recently-used files.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
'
' Silent SaveAsPDF Macro
'
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
    If ActiveDocument.Saved = True Then 
      RecentFiles.Add Document:=ActiveDocument.Name 
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
Add the line after all

> [RecentFiles.Add Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.recentfiles.add)

```vb
Sub SaveAsPDF()
'
' Silent SaveAsPDF Macro
'

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
    RecentFiles.Add Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf")
End Sub
```

#### OR

```vb
Sub SaveAsPDF()

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
            Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), wdFormatPDF, , , True
    RecentFiles.Add Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf")
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like this should help, I just need to pick up the full path information into it,

Comment: @Goodday If everything is OK, please accept this answer to end this question for future reference, thank you.